# Python-can Logging File Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, logging, python-can

I just got started with Python-can and I need to edit the reporting format of the built in Logging feature. Below is a snippet of the code that I am referring too.

```
logger = can.Logger('log3.asc')
```

This is the resulting header from the log file:

```
date Mon Jun 06 04:56:40.184122 PM 2020
base hex  timestamps absolute
internal events logged
Begin Triggerblock Wed Dec 12 10:17:48.038 PM 1969
0.000000 Start of measurement
0.000000 1  300             Rx   d 6 00 00 14 CF BE FF
```

The issue is in the first line, I can't have the time reported in microseconds, milliseconds is the furthest I can go. Is there anyway to edit that value within python-can? Or does this require extra code to manually go into the log file and stripe those values?

Thank you for the time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot change it. In the source code of python-can, it use %f to generate microsecond and no constant variable there for redefinition.

```
class ASCWriter(BaseIOHandler, Listener):
    ...
    def __init__(self, file, channel=1):
        ...
        # write start of file header
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%a %b %m %I:%M:%S.%f %p %Y")
        self.file.write("date %s\n" % now)
        self.file.write("base hex  timestamps absolute\n")
        self.file.write("internal events logged\n")
        ...
```

If you try to change the format of %f in datetime.strftime, the same situation, it set the digit as '%06d', also no constant variable there for redifinition.

```py
def _wrap_strftime(object, format, timetuple):
    ...
                if ch == 'f':
                    if freplace is None:
                        freplace = '%06d' % getattr(object,
                                                    'microsecond', 0)
    ...
```

I think the only way is to change the source code of py-can or datetime, but it is not suggested !!

Comment: That's unfortunate. Back to the drawing board. Thanks for the explanation @Jason Yang!

Comment: Maybe you can try logging, 3-digit ms is default setting, and you can set your format for datetime.

Comment: You mean, try to establish the logging from the ground up instead of using the can.logger class within the python-can package?

Comment: yes, sometime for special requirements .And sometime build yourself logger : )

Comment: I suppose I didn't think about that. Thank you for the help Jason. I appreciate it.